# Is there a difference between elem['textContent'] and elem.textContent?

Tags: javascript

In `JavaScript`, is there a difference between

`elem['textContent'] = "Test";`

and

`elem.textContent = "Test";`

when `elem` is a `HTMLElement`?

Comment: `elem.['textContent']` is invalid syntax, I guess you mean `elem['textContent']` (no dot). If this is the case, the two are functionally identical.

Comment: @CristiPufu I'm not sure if silently removing the syntax error is a good thing to do while editing questions. It might be there because it's really in the OPs code and thus should be discussed.

Comment: you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**They do the same.** They set the property on the object (it can be any type of object, so it does not make a difference whether it is an `HTMLElement`, `Function` or any other object).

The only difference is that you can pass an [**expression**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions) into the bracket notation, while the other form only allows names that [qualify as an **identifier**](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-2/identifiers-and-reserved-words).

For example:

```
elem['text' + 'Content'] = "Test"; //works

var t = ['textContent'];
elem[t[0]] = "Test"; //works

elem[(function () { return 'textContent'; })()] = "Test"; //works
```